# wordpress query orderby author role

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have multi authors with different roles and I need to order posts by author's role. 
for example: there are 3 authors with roles: admin, editor, customer and all of them can publish post.
now, how I can order sites's posts by authors roles?
First ADMIN posts
second EDITOR posts
and last CUSTOMER posts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below code to get the post by user role :

```
 function get_posts_by_role_user($role) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ps.* FROM {$wpdb->posts} ps, {$wpdb->usermeta} ur"
                                ." WHERE    ps.post_type     = 'post'"
                                ." AND      ps.post_status   = 'publish'"
                                ." AND      ur.user_id       = ps.`post_author`"
                                ." AND      ur.meta_key      = 'wp_capabilities'"
                                ." AND      ur.meta_value    LIKE '%\"{$role}\"%'" );
}
```

**declare your all role**

```
  $roles = array('admin','editor','customer');
```

**loop according to role**

```
 foreach($roles as $key => $role  ){
      $user_posts = get_posts_by_role_user($role);
        foreach($user_posts as $spost){ 
          echo $spost->post_title, '<br />';
        }
   }
```

Paste above all the code in your current active theme **functions.php** file.

Comment: hey dineshkashera, thanks for this solution. it works for me

Comment: pleasure to help you @elnaz :)